# Is there a way to access and edit Apple's Reminders.app database from Android?

Tags: sync

Is there a way to access and edit Apple's Reminders.app database from Android, I didn't find a way to do it, how can I do that?

*(searching both google and play store I've found tons of unrelated stuff, and exactly **zero** related)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to sync reminders to your Android device described on [CNet](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-sync-icloud-reminders-with-your-android-device/). The solution consists of two apps, [SmoothSync for Cloud Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.caldav.icloud) and [Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dmfs.tasks). With this combination, you'll have a separate reminder-style app that syncs with your iCloud account.

First buy and install SmoothSync and add your iCloud account to it. After this, install Tasks and wait a couple of minutes for the sync to happen, and after this the setup is complete and ready to use.

Comment: Thanks, apparently I got some of these programs individually, but I missed the big picture!